# Prove that $\sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^{m+1} {n \choose m} \frac{1}{m+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to prove that:

$$\sum_{m=1}^{n} (-1)^{m+1} {n \choose m} \frac{1}{m+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}$$

I've tried to prove this by induction and directly, without luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $$\int_0^1x^m\,dx=\dfrac{1}{m+1}.$$ Also I am pretty sure that this question has been asked here before.

Comment: As an alternate way of tackling this (and a general tool), you could write ${n\choose m}={n\choose n-m}$ and see if you can write a generating function for the LHS as a product of simpler generating functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Use the identity

$$\binom{n}m\frac1{m+1}=\binom{n+1}{m+1}\frac1{n+1}\,.$$

I’ve taken it a step further in the spoiler block below.

> $$\begin{align*}\sum_{m=1}^n(-1)^{m+1}\binom{n}m\frac1{m+1}&=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{m=1}^n(-1)^{m+1}\binom{n+1}{m+1}\\&=\frac1{n+1}\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(-1)^k\binom{n+1}k\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out with your generous hint.

Comment: @Eragon20: You’re welcome; I’m delighted that you were able to finish it off on your own after all.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try to multiply by $n+1$ and note that ${n\choose m}\frac{n+1}{m+1}= {n+1\choose m+1}$. Then use Newton's binomial to expand $(1-1)^{n+1}$.